# Using of prebuilt .so file without other files

Tags: android, c++, c, android-studio, .so

Actually i have a pre-built **.so** file. but i have no header files and and c files. can i use it in android studio for execution and what will be the changes have to be made in the build gradle of app? please help me..

my build gradle is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.acsiatech.microfuzzy.samplejniinterface"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate header file (\*.h) for on shared library file (\*.so)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197109/generate-header-file-h-for-on-shared-library-file-so)

Comment: what are the essential other components to be added rather than the .so file for its proper working?

Comment: Shall i use Cmakelists.txt instead of using android.mk?

Comment: i created a folder called jniLibs in /app/src/main/ and in the folder x86, put the corresponding .so file. and after that it is not done anything. but, while building it not builds. is there anything i have to do additionally to get the project into build?